# How to make two floated (one to right, one to left) div's not to "jump" if the container div is resized too small?

Tags: html, css, floating

The question sounds complex but here is HTML that illustrates it:

```
<div id="contained" style="overflow: hidden">
 <div id="float-right" style="float: right; width: 100px">floated-right</div>
 <div id="float-left" style="float: left; width: 200px">floated-left</div>

 <div style="clear: both"></div>
</div>
```

If I resize `#contained` to less than `300px` then `#float-left` jumps below it and is no longer visible.

Question is: How do I prevent `#float-left` from disappearing if I resize `#contained` to less than `300px`? How do I make `#float-right` and `#float-left` "stick together" if `#contained` is less than `300px`?

Comment: you could use a media query and max-width on the floated divs

Comment: Floated div widht never changes though. Do you mean on container div? Its width also is actually not defined it changes are more elements are added to both floated right or floated left. The big question is how to make floated elements not to overflow the container.

Comment: then a media query that removes the floats and changes the div to display:inline-block

Comment: @FunkDoc Thanks. I have never used media query. Could you illustrate how that would approximately look like (what i'd have to write?)

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to prevent `#float-left` from disappearing when the container `#contained` is resized to less than `300px` - *and* has `overflow:hidden` *and* a fixed height (presumably) - because `#float-left` and `#float-right` have fixed widths of `100px` and `200px`. If you would like them to remain side by side you would need to give them percentage widths. You could also have them stack one on top of the other if you give the `#container`  `height: auto`.

```
<div id="contained" style="overflow: hidden">
 <div id="float-right" style="float: right; width: 33.3%">floated-right</div>
 <div id="float-left" style="float: left; width: 66.6%">floated-left</div>

 <div style="clear: both"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks I will try this. What about the reamining 0.1% though?

Comment: You could try and get closer by going to two decimal points (eg. 33.33% and 66.66%), but I recommend testing it to ensure that the divs still fit side by side in all browsers.

Comment: Thanks! I think I'll go 34% and 66% so that it's 100% precisely. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a media query to change the style when the page is below a certain width. Example:

```css
body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }

#contained { overflow: hidden; background: #f8f8f8; }
#float-right { float: right; width: 200px; background: #ffc; }
#float-left { float: left; width: 300px; background: #ccf; }

@media (max-width: 500px) {
  
  #float-right { width: 33.33%; }
  #float-left { width: 66.66%; }
  
}
```

```html
<div id="contained">
 <div id="float-right">floated-right</div>
 <div id="float-left">floated-left</div>
</div>
```

Note: You don't need a clearing element inside the container, as the `overflow` style will make it contain its children.